# Nested IIF statement in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having a problem with a simple nested IIF statement on SSRS. I am trying to do the second part where if the number is a `"-"` then it should return a `"-"`.

`=IIF(Fields!fbrt_number.Value < "0",Fields!fbrt_number.Value, "+")`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're exactly after. I'm assuming you want to prefix all numbers (including positive numbers and zero) with a sign.

Here's what your code currently does:

- Compares `fbrt_number`'s value with the *string* "0"
- Depending on the result either show the fields' value, or a plus sign

Are you perhaps after this:

```
=IIF(Fields!fbrt_number.Value < 0, 
     "-" + Fields!fbrt_number.Value.ToString(),
     "+" + Fields!fbrt_number.Value.ToString())
```

This will compare the field value to the number 0, and depending on the result prefix a "-" or a "+".

Or, if you want to display just a "+" for positive values, and a "-" for negatives:

```
=IIF(Fields!fbrt_number.Value < 0, 
     "-",
     "+")
```

Finally, if you want an empty string for 0 then this will work:

```
=IIF(Fields!fbrt_number.Value < 0, 
     "-",
     IIF(Fields!fbrt_number.Value > 0, "+", ""))
```

Note that if your field isn't actually a number yet you may need to cast it first (either in your dataset query, or using SSRS expressions).

Comment: That does bring back the "+" or "-" but I don't want the actual values. All I want to return is the "+" or "-"

Comment: Fair enough, added those options to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had the same thing down but I was missing out the `""` hence why I was getting stuck. As a general question, why are the double quotes needed on the end of it?

Comment: `IIF` has three parameters, respectively a test, the "if-true" value and the "if-false" value. The final "" covers the case where the value is zero and the output should be an empty string (i.e. no sign).

Comment: Thanks, I have never ever used this in Excel hence why the confusion.